# Negative Correlation and Securities?

Tags: probability, statistics

The following is a problem in the textbook I am trying to do as I practice for an exam. I would appreciate some help on this question

I have completed part a. I have determined expected return in part B and C. I know how to find the risk but I am not sure how to find the covariance. Part D I have no idea.

Consider two securities, the first having $μ_1 = 1$ and $σ_1 = 0.1$, and the second
having $μ_2 = 0.8$ and $σ_2 = 0.12$. Suppose that they are negatively correlated,
with $ρ = −0.8$.

a) If you could only invest in one security, which one would you choose, and why?

b) Suppose you invest 50% of your money in each of the two. What is your expected return and what is your risk? What if $ρ=0.1$?

c) If you invest 80% of your money in security 1 and 20% in security 2, what
is your expected return and your risk? What if $ρ=0.1$?

Comment: Just look up the definitions of expected value and standard deviation and apply them!

Comment: Still confused?

Comment: I was able to figure out part A, and most of part b and c.